# javascript current time not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a project to do, make a karaoke in javascript. When the song goes, the lyrics has to follow.

My code html :

```
<div id="lyric"></div>
<audio id="audioPlayer" controls>
    <source src="http://supjs.fr/DEV2018/myKaraoke/music/LOR.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Lyrics in text file:

[00:00.00]Fanuilos heryn aglar

[00:10.00]RÃ®n athar annÃºn-aearath

[00:20.00]Calad ammen i reniar

[00:30.00]Mi'aladhremmin ennorath

[00:40.00]A Elbereth! Gilthoniel!

[00:50.00]I chÃ®n a thÃ»l lin mÃ­riel

[01:00.00]Fanuilos! Le linnathon

[01:09.00]Ne ndor haer that i aearon

[01:20.00]A elin na gaim eglerib

[01:30.00]Ned Ã®n ben-anor trerennin

[01:39.00]Si silivrin ne pherth 'waewib

[01:48.00]Cenim lyth lthÃ­lyn thuiennin

[01:58.00]A Elbereth Gilthoniel

[02:08.00]Men echenim sÃ­ derthiel

[02:17.00]Ne chaered hen nu'aladhath

[02:27.00]Ngilith or annÃºn-aearath

And javascript :

```
window.onload = function(){
var track = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');

track.ontimeupdate = function(){
    console.log(this.currentTime);
    if (this.currentTime > 0 && this.curentTime < 9){
        getRSS(0);
    }
};
};
function getRSS(i) {

var rss = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log("hello");
rss.open('GET', 'lyrics.txt', false);
console.log("hello1");
rss.send(null);
console.log("hello");
var ligne = rss.responseText.split(/\n/g);/* Stock tout le fichier dans la variable (tableau)*/
console.log("hello");
var linkRss = ligne[i];
document.write(linkRss);

}
```

And it does not work, the line appears but the music stop and the audio disappear, I don't understand what is happening can someone help me ?

Comment: You have a typo in your code: `this.curentTime` should be `this.currentTime`. I'll post an answer in a minute.

Comment: Oh yes thx, but I guess this is not the problem it's still not working :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that you're **overwriting** your page with the `document.write(linkRss);` statement.

You have to append text to your div element, not to your whole document.

```
document.getElementById('lyric').innerHTML += linkRss;
```

Please notice that you're mixing time based code with asynchronous code, which will be tricky to handle and impossible to run with the intended behaviour.

Comment: Ok thank you it works better, ok I'm going to look at that

Answer (score 0):

try this,maybe:
new Date().getTime()

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to elaborate the answer with code. So that it can be helpful to the future user.